# Writing style for modular arithmetic with multiple equivalences in a single line or split between multiple lines

Tags: modular-arithmetic, article-writing

Is this a valid notation in modular arithmetic?

$$ 2 \equiv 12 \equiv 22 \equiv 32 \pmod{10}. $$

If I want to split this into multiple lines (say, I have got expressions that are very long), then what is the right way to write this? Is this okay?

\begin{align*}
2 & \equiv 12 \\
  & \equiv 22 \\
  & \equiv 32 \pmod{10}.
\end{align*}

Or do I need to write it like this?

\begin{align*}
2 & \equiv 12 \pmod{10} \\
  & \equiv 22 \pmod{10} \\
  & \equiv 32 \pmod{10}.
\end{align*}

Comment: You can also write $2=12=22=32$ in the ring $\Bbb Z_{10}$, or split it into several lines. It is all the same. So yes, it is valid.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is the last form where I repeat $\pmod{10}$ in every line also an acceptable form?

Comment: I see no problem with this. It is like writing $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=0$, it is clear what is meant. The other ways are acceptable as well.

Comment: For long expressions, I suggest variation $2$

Comment: It isn't necessary to repeat the $(\operatorname{mod} 10)$ on every line; I'd just put it at the end.

Comment: @Peter By variation 2 do you mean the one that repeats (mod 10) on every line?

Comment: No, with "mod 10" only once (the first is the one with one line)

Comment: I like to compromise between putting too many copies of (mod $n$) and being too vague by using $a \equiv_n b \equiv_n c \equiv_n d.$ I find that the subscript of $n$ is a subtle reminder where everything is taking place.